# ios stop 2 threads from using a method at the same time

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading

<strike>We had a bug, and it destroys the looks of our UI, some of the UI elements overlap, or has been added to the subview twice. the bug is hardly reproduced so its hard to fix it. Now I thought of the reason, and probably the method that changes the UI are being called twice at the same time. And I was correct, I tried to create the bug programatically.</strike>

We have a bug which is caused by a method being accessed by different threads at the same time. To emulate this problem, and better understand it. see codes posted below.

When I do this, updatePresence Method call, my program works perfectly

ViewController.m

```
-(void)loadConversationScreen{
    [conversationController updatePresence];
}
```

But when I do this, something goes wrong with my program

ViewController.m

```
-(void)loadConversationScreen{
    [conversationController performSelectorInBackground:@selector(updatePresence) withObject:nil];
    [conversationController updatePresence];

}
```

<strike>This is because the method is being accessed at the same time and and the instance of my UIView is being accessed/changed also at the same time.</strike>

How do I ***PROPERLY*** stop 2 threads from using a method at the same time?

How do I properly handle it in IOS(if there is no proper way, what are the work arounds), are there built in locks or somekind?

My app should support ios 4.0 and up

Advance thanks to all for your help.

Comment: Never update your UI on a background thread. UIKit strictly forbids it.

Comment: uhmmm thanks, I dont know that, but that is only a test to try to update it using two different threads at the same time. The bug is hard to reproduce, but it happens when two threads access the method at same time as I noted above

Comment: performSelectorInBackground is only used to emulate accessing of method on different threads, but I'm actually not doing it in our code. Thanks for informing me that it is illegal. I learned something new. So can anybody help me with my question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best thread lock for you is `@sycnhronized(object) {}`. This means only one thread can enter the code at a time. The object passed in is used to perform the lock; only one thread can enter a block protected by a particular object's synchronized at a time. The others will wait. This can be any Objective-C object, even a `NSString`.

Typically, you'd use whatever object you're trying to protect from multiple threads. You probably want `@synchronized(self) {}`:

```
-(void)updateVariables {
    @synchronized(self) {
        _foo = 1;
        _bar = 2;
    }
}
```

`@sycnhronized` is re-entrant in the sense that the same thread can call `@sycnhronized` as deeply as it wants, for instance:

```
- (void)a {
    @synchronized(self) {
        // entered "immediately" if called from b, where the @synchronized has
        // already been called
        _foo = _foo + 1;
    }
}

- (void)b {
    @synchronized(self) {
        [self a];
    }
}
```

For posterity and because I already typed it before reading your clarification, if you really cared only about updating the UI, you'd want to force your call over to the main thread instead like this:

```
- (void)someTask {
    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self updateUI];
    });
}

- (void)updateUI {
    NSAssert( [NSThread isMainThread], @"called from non-main thread" );
    // do UI updates here
}
```

Comment: I tried to research that @synchronized thing, it's my first time to use it, can you give me a short example on how synchronized can be applied on my code?

Comment: Anyway thanks for this answer, I'll just do more research about this and search tutorials. Thanks man

Answer (score 2):

As warrenm said you shouldn't update your `UIView` from a different thread than the Main thread (UI thread). Still, you asked if there is any workaround for what's going on. To be honest, you should try to, instead of blocking the access of the second thread to your method, understand why the methods is called twice. This is more a logical problem than anything else and you should try to fix that, instead of trying a shortcut.

Comment: I understand that I should try to understand why the method is called twice, but the bug on our program  almost doesnt happen, so I was forced to find a way to reproduce it programatically. Thanks for the advice anyway. My question is more on How to stop 2 threads from accessing a method at the same time, even if it will update other variables/object and not UI

Comment: In this case check what Steven Fisher recommended.